# NSClosableWindowMask dialog acting strange

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow

I have a Safari browser plugin, and in it, I want to open an NSWindow to display a copyright note. While the Ok button in the dialog closes the dialog's window, and works perfectly, when I click on the red close window "x" in the top left corner, it also closes the window, but it's parent window (the entire browser tab, I had the plugin running in), remains disabled, as if still a modal window was open somewhere.

I even tried to attach a new selector to the window close notification, which runs the same code as the Ok button, but still, it's not working properly.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
- (void) closeBox
{
    // called when the Ok button pressed
    [NSApp abortModal];

}

- (void)closeClicked:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // called when the close window 'x' button pressed
    NSLog(@"Closed");
    [NSApp abortModal];
}


- (void) openBox
{
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
     mwin  = [[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                     styleMask:NSClosableWindowMask |NSTitledWindowMask
                                       backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                         defer:NO] autorelease];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(closeClicked:)
                                             name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                           object:mwin];
    NSButton * bn;
    bn = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 20) ] autorelease];

    [bn setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
    [bn setTitle:@"Ok"];
    [bn setTarget:self];
    [bn setAction:@selector(closeBox)];

    [[mwin contentView] addSubview:bn];

    [NSApp runModalForWindow:mwin];   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of googling, I found others had similar problems, and the solution is pretty simple: the window object was retained by the NSNotificationCenter's observer. All I had to do it is to remove the observer:

```
- (void) closeClicked:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [NSApp abortModal];

    NSLog(@"Closed");

}
```

Now it's working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code try like this below:-

```
- (void) closeBox
{
    // called when the Ok button pressed
  //Commented this line 
 // [NSApp abortModal];

    [mwin performClose:mwin];// Modified this line 


}

   //Modified below notification just comment the parameter
    - (void)closeClicked/*:(NSNotification *)notification*/
    {

    [NSApp abortModal];

}


- (void) openBox
{
    NSRect frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 300, 250);
    mwin  = [[[[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:frame
                                         styleMask:NSClosableWindowMask |NSTitledWindowMask
                                           backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                            defer:NO]retain]autorelease];
  //Modified notification below    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(closeClicked)
                                                 name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
                                               object:nil];
    NSButton * bn;
    bn = [[[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10, 10, 100, 20) ] autorelease];

    [bn setButtonType:NSMomentaryPushInButton];
    [bn setTitle:@"Ok"];
    [bn setTarget:self];
    [bn setAction:@selector(closeBox)];

    [[mwin contentView] addSubview:bn];

    [NSApp runModalForWindow:mwin];   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately this didn't solve my problem, the symptom is still the same: after the dialog disappears, I can't click any more. 
Your modification in closeBox() is pointless anyway, when using the 'x' to close the window, it is not called at all. Do you happen to have any other idea?

Comment: @Mkoch, I have modified closeClicked method in which if you need to comment notification parameter it will called when you click on x button. Also did you completely run my code??

Comment: Also its working fine for me. Did you observingthe notification??

Comment: Yes, closeClicked is called indeed, I was just talking about the closeBox method. And yes, I did copy and merge the whole code line-by-line. Can you reproduce the problem with my original code?

Comment: Actually using `[mwin performClose:mwin]` instead of `[NSApp abortModal]` in the `closeBox` as you suggest, results a crash on my side when clicking the previously working "Ok" button `bn`.

Comment: But for me its working fine and if you use [NSApp abortModal] then what its happening??

Comment: `[NSApp abortModal]` works well when called by the button `bn`'s click event, while the same thing doesn't work when I call it from the window close 'x' button.

Comment: Using your code, when the Ok button is clicked, it hangs the program (the dialog is still visible, the Ok button pushed in), and everything is frozen for 1-2mins. Then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS for the `[mwin performClose:mwin]` within the `closeBox()` method

Comment: Did you try [mwin close] inspite of using performClose??